# How to change the legend of my barchart in angular

Tags: angular

How to change the postion of legend from top to bottom in nvd3 chart.

[image]

```
 options = {
"chart": {
  "type": "multiBarChart",
  "height": 300,
  "margin": {
    "top": 20,
    "right": 20,
    "bottom": 45,
    "left": 45
  },
  "clipEdge": true,
  "duration": 500,
  "stacked": false,
  "xAxis": {
    // "axisLabel": "Time (ms)",
    "showMaxMin": false
  },
  "yAxis": {
    // "axisLabel": "Y Axis",
    "axisLabelDistance": -20,
    tickFormat:
      function (d) {
        return d3.format('0f')(d);
      }

  },
  showControls: false,
  color: ["#71B84F", "#FFC300"],
}
```

link i am using to create bar chart.
https://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/multiBarChart

Comment: Hi Rohit you shouldn't update your question with a new one, you should ask a new question please get back the old question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add : `legendPosition: 'bottom'`

Example :

```
 options = {
"chart": {
  "type": "multiBarChart",
  "height": 300,
  "margin": {
    "top": 20,
    "right": 20,
    "bottom": 45,
    "left": 45
  },
  "clipEdge": true,
  "duration": 500,
  "stacked": false,
  "xAxis": {
    // "axisLabel": "Time (ms)",
    "showMaxMin": false
  },
  "yAxis": {
    // "axisLabel": "Y Axis",
    "axisLabelDistance": -20,
    tickFormat:
      function (d) {
        return d3.format('0f')(d);
      }

  },
  showControls: false,
  color: ["#71B84F", "#FFC300"],
  legend: {
      margin: {
        top: 5, right: 1, bottom: 1, left: 1
      },            
  },
  legendPosition: 'bottom'
}
```

Comment: can I apply margin-left css property to it to make it looking good.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other chart types, `multiBarChart` has not property `legendPosition`. Therefore, you need to define [`legend.margin`](http://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#legend) and play around with values for `top` and `bottom`.

```
chart: {
  ...
  legend: {
    margin : {
      top: 220,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 20,
      left: 45
    }
  },
  ...
```

Comment: Hello where I need to use the above properties.I am getting error when I am using these in chart object.

Comment: The hierarchy is `options.chart.legend.margin`